# Структура базы данных в большом проекте

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Хочу сделать проект, в котором будет много клиентов.

Допустим, у каждого клиента будут свои товары, заказы, клиенты и т.д.

База нужна для сайта и для админки.

То есть, пользователь авторизовался и ему показало данные с его базы.

Как лучше сделать структуру базы данных и какую лучше использовать?

Comment: @АлинаЛуцковская, Вы сделайте структуру, покажите её здесь - в Вашем вопросе. А мы Вам постараемся подсказать как эту структуру улучшить. А может, Вы её сразу сделаете на 100% верной...

Comment: Клиентов будет много и у каждого будут свои хотелки и параметры заказов, своя структура каталогов, свои уникальные теги и т.д.?  Нагрузка планируется огромная - такая что с ней не справится один сервер?  Заказчик сам будет планировать бизнес-процессы с документами - или дергать программистов каждый раз при изменении процесса?  Просто на самом деле описание недостаточно.  Слишком разные варианты подходят.  Опишите свой - мы подскажем потенциальные проблемы

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов - сделать для каждого клиента отдельную базу.

Плюс для админки еще одна база, в которой каждому клиенту сопоставляется его база и его персональный раздел сайта (например, client_name.example.com/ или example.com/client_name/). Это позволит, при необходимости, разнести клиентов по разным серверам.